# How to replace a text-align: -webkit-center?

Tags: html, css, webkit

The use of webkit CSS properties is not recommended due the non-standarized. Refactoring some code I've found I'm using a `text-align: -webkit-center` in my CSS:

```
.wrap-block {
    text-align: -webkit-center;
}
```

in order to center some blocks of text:

```
p {
    max-width: 200px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

in a structure similar to this one:

```
<div class="main-block">
    <div class="wrap-block">
        <p>Some random text</p>
        <img ... />
        <p>...</p>
        <blockquote>Unlimited width for this</blockquote>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdg35y69/) shows an example.

How to get rid of this webkit property? How to replace using standard HTML or CSS?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sdg35y69/1/

Comment: text-align:justify !important  is it

Comment: @GopsAB — No, the paragraphs are already justified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align):

> **The standard-compatible way to center a block** itself without centering its inline content is setting the left and right margin to auto, e.g.:
>   `margin:auto;` or `margin:0 auto;` or  `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`

So:

```
.wrap-block {
    text-align: center;
}

.wrap-block p,
.wrap-block blockquote {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you can/want to use flexbox, you can use the following as well.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```