# Why do browser prefixes for text-align have different behaviour and which is correct?

Tags: css, cross-browser, webkit, mozilla, vendor-prefix

I want to vertically centre `<div>` tags that have a horizontal margin between each other.

The problem is that this behavior appears to be inconsistent between `text-align: center` and `text-align: -webkit-center` or `text-align: -moz-center`:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted #fd0;
  position: relative;
}
.parent.ta {
  text-align: center;
}
.parent.browser-ta {
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  text-align: -moz-center;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.child > .content {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
.wrong {
  background-color: #e00;
  color: #fff;
}
.right {
  background-color: #0a3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Using <tt>text-align: center</tt>;
  <div class="parent ta">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="content wrong">child 1 LEFT</div>
      <div class="parent ta">
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child b</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child c</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="content wrong">child 2 LEFT</div>
      <div class="parent ta">
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child d</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child e</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child f</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child ">
      <div class="content right">child 3 CENTRE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div>
  Using <tt>text-align: -vendor-center</tt>
  <div class="parent browser-ta">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="content right">child 1 CENTRE</div>
      <div class="parent browser-ta">
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child b</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child c</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="content right">child 2 CENTRE</div>
      <div class="parent browser-ta">
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child d</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child e</div>
        </div>
        <div class="child">
          <div class="content">child f</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div class="content right">child 3 CENTRE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Run that snippet and the two similar HTML and CSS produce different layouts in Chrome (Webkit/Blink) and FireFox. The red panels are in the wrong location, the green ones are correct.

So `text-align: -webkit-center` and `text-align: -moz-center` appear to be correct (to me) but `text-align: center` appears to be bugged in both browsers.

Digging out the venerable old `<centre>` tag (that we're not supposed to use) and that works right too (though examining it reveals it uses the browser prefix too).

Is this correct? Is this a bug? Is there a reason for the difference? Which one should I use?

Comment: I've never seen that property vendor prefixed...do you have a reference for doing so.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588137/how-to-replace-a-text-align-webkit-center

Comment: @Paulie_D no I don't, but I have included a snippet that runs and demonstrates the different behaviour. If you have the relevant explicit documentation then that would probably be a good answer. The alternate question you cited is relevant but has a very different solution - `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work for me as I want a consistent margin between the children.

Comment: The vendor prefixed version are non-normative and so implementations will be different. I suspect you should be looking into flexbox which, I believe, will supercede this property.

Comment: @Paulie_D That would usually be my assumption, however the behaviour of the prefixed properties are clearly more correct - all the children are `display: inline-block;` so should be centred, which `text-align: -prefix-center;` *does do* and `text-align: center;` **does not do**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefixed values are described by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) to be "block alignment values", which means block boxes themselves are aligned in addition to the inline content within them. This is the exact behavior of the `<center>` element, and the prefixed values are in fact *intended for that element* — if you look in the UA stylesheets for each engine you'll find a ruleset that says exactly `center { display: block; text-align: -vendor-center; }`.

The reason `text-align: center` is not implemented this way is because `text-align` is designed to affect inline-level boxes (as evidenced by the "text-" in its name), not block-level boxes. But that, I suspect, is not the answer you're really looking for.

What's happening is that the boxes that are actually being aligned in your snippet are the `.content` elements, which are block boxes, not inline-blocks. The reason that last element *is* being centred is because its parent, an inline-block, is being shrink-wrapped, and itself then centred by the `text-align: center` declaration in its ancestor.

Comment: Ah! So `text-align: center` only applies to inline and inline-block elements, but `text-align: -vendor-center` applies to block elements too? OK, that helps and gives me a way to fix it. Frustrating though: I get that `<center>` conflates presentation and content, but it's survived because the CSS alternatives don't do what it reliably does (auto margins and -50% translations are both cludges).